# Create a custom XML indexing connector for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, content-source

I am new to search service application and want to create content source of Custom Repository and found that there is no Custom Connectors Registered.

So i have go through the articles and found the below articles

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xml_connector_for_sharepoint_2013/2012/10/01/create-a-custom-xml-indexing-connector-for-sharepoint-2013/

It needs the **XmlFileConnector.dll** which can be downloaded from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nadeemis/2012/06/04/implementing-a-sharepoint-xml-indexing-connector/

But when i check the project folder, there is no dll.

It will be really helpful if anyone suggest me blog/article using which i can create custom connector

Comment: I think this is the [dll ](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-55-87-Trimming/6786.Connector.zip) you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is available here . Please Click this link https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/MSDNBlogsFS/prod.evol.blogs.msdn.com/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00/10/35/46/94/XmlFileConnector.zip  and extract the files and you would find the dll inside "XmlFileConnector\bin\Debug" Folder